# Can we use Meta for hat-farming?

Tags: discussion

So, with WinterBash upon us all, there's one very important question that everyone is asking:

> **How do I get more hats?!**

Can we use the Meta site to test our and try to get more hats (provided we delete the questions after)?

Comment: I don't think meta counts for hats anymore (except ones that mention it in their description).

Comment: @Seth According to the hat room, they do count.

Comment: I just checked with an SE employee. Only [meta.se] counts.

Comment: @Seth Aww. Lame!

Comment: I also think farming for hats is a bit against the spirit of the hats :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Marco says, this is a bit against the spirit of the hats. Actually I'd go as far as to say it's against the rules. Hats are like badges, they're (mostly) supposed to encourage good behaviors, not trigger a mad dash to "catch 'em all" in the fastest way possible and the heck with the consequences to the health of the site.

And beside all that... as Seth pointed out, "farming" on meta won't even work for most hats.